# How to set custom view class for view controller without the storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to programmatically perform this feature provided by the storyboard: by setting the view class in the storyboard, in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` period, you can directly get an instance of the desired custom view class. Is there some API like `-registerViewClass:` which can register the custom view class at the initialization period?

I do this by replacing the original UIView instance in the `-(void)viewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   self.view = [[CustomViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:(self.view.frame)];
}
```

it works, but not most efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your view controller's subclass, you should override `loadView` and assign your custom view like so:

`-(void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[MYCustomView alloc] init];
}`

This is the preferred method of swapping out the class of the view loaded by the view controller subclass. `viewDidLoad` should be used only for additional initialization of your views.

Answer (score 1):

This code can create customview in code and add it in full screen when you use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   CustomViewClass customView = [[CustomViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.view = customView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I'd like to discard the original view, which is useless for me. Especially in my case, I created a custom view controller class and a custom view class, and they will communicate with each other by invoking the instance methods, not protocol. For the protocol will increase the complexity dramatically, and in case of the view and view controller know each other very well, they can invoke the instance methods safely. So, I think there is no need to retain the original UIView instance, just replacing it is OK and more efficient

Comment: change self.view = customView;

Comment: That's what I did, my question is, whether there is an API to register the custom view class during the initializing period to improve the overall efficiency.